# JQuery Date Picker - Limiting possible selections

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am currently using this JQuery datepicker from http://www.eyecon.ro/datepicker/.

I have looked through the implementation document to see whether it is possible to prevent a user from selecting any future dates but I am unable to find any reference to this kind of option.

Is it possible to do so using this date picker?

As things stand, here is the date pickers script:

```
<script type=text/javascript>
$('#inputDate').DatePicker({
    format:'m/d/Y',
    date: new Date(),
    current: $('#inputDate').val(),
    starts: 1,
    position: 'right',
    onBeforeShow: function(){
        $('#inputDate').DatePickerSetDate($('#inputDate').val(), true);
    },
    onChange: function(formated, dates){
        $('#inputDate').val(formated);
        if ($('#closeOnSelect input').attr('checked')) {
            $('#inputDate').DatePickerHide();
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would suggest doing validations on both client-end and server-end, even though the maxDate option is available.

Since it is nearly impossible to guarantee that client submition would be always correct.
Some time user can submit request with out using browser. (e.g. fiddler)

Comment: I ended up carrying out the validation using PHP and it works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not add some validation to that onChange function?

And by the way I would probably use the datepicker that is bundled with jqueryui unless you really need some of the features of that specific plugin. It hasn't been updated in 2 years and eventually will no longer be compatible with the latest jQuery core library (assuming it still is).

Answer (score 0):

the option is called `maxDate`.  Set it to `new Date()`